# 'Observable<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, observable, httpclient

I would like to call an http request which must return an observable which is then subscribed by
a method which is called with specific time interval for further ...

Please consider this

**Subscriber method**

```
 startReceivingMeasurmentLiveDataV2(httpOptions: any,deviceId:number,seriesType:string,aggregation:string,from:string,to:string,pageSize:number,revert:boolean) {
debugger;
if (this.intervalSubscription) {
  this.intervalSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

this.intervalSubscription = interval(200)
  .pipe(
    takeWhile(() => this.alive),
//    switchMap(() => this.deviceService.getMeasurmentLiveUpdateCardDataV2(httpOptions,deviceId,seriesType,aggregation,from,to,pageSize,revert)),
    switchMap(() => this.deviceService.GetMeasurmentsV2(httpOptions,deviceId,seriesType,aggregation,from,to,pageSize,revert)),
  )
  .subscribe((liveUpdateChartData: any[]) => {

  debugger;
    this.liveUpdateChartData = [...liveUpdateChartData];
```

//console.log("measurment data");
//   console.log(this.liveUpdateChartData);
});
}

**Http Observable**

```
GetMeasurmentsV2(httpOptions: any, deviceID: number, seriesType: string, aggregationType: string, dateFrom: string, dateTo: string, pageSize: number, revert: boolean):  Observable<any[]>  {
let url =  `${this.config.apiUrl}/measurement/measurements/series?aggregationType='${aggregationType}'&dateFrom='${dateFrom}'&dateTo='${dateTo}'&pageSize='${pageSize}'&revert='${revert}'&series='${seriesType}'&source='${deviceID}'`
url = url.replace(/'/g,'');  


return this.httpClient.get<any>(

     url

      ,httpOptions)
      
      .pipe(map(measurments => {
        return observableOf(measurments);

     
      }));
```

}

Now here is the issue

[image]

Please help me how can I fix this?

Comment: where does `observableOf ` come from?

Comment: from rxjs libraray

Comment: i can't find it at all on the rxjs documentation (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api). Can you provide the import part ?

Comment: it's only "of" these days instead of observableOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a nested observable right now

just return the initial observable `return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, httpOptions)`, without wrapping the response in another observable

Comment: which version of angular are you using?